# Joining a windows server foundation edition as a member server to server essential network?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I am planing to purchase an entry level hp proliant server with oem windows server foundation 2012 for installing an erp server and database on it.

we already have windows server 2012 essential r2 dc in our office. Will i be able to join the windows server foundation to window server essential domain as a member server.

This is what the Microsoft website says about it .

"In the Windows Server 2012 Foundation operating system, the server must be a member of a work group or, if joined to a domain, joined at the root of the forest as a domain controller. You will receive a warning message if the server is not joined to an Active Directory® domain at the root of the forest. If you do not correct this, you will receive notifications advising you of the violation of the terms of the license agreement. Eventually, the server will shut down. If your server is not joined to the domain at the root of the forest, disjoint the domain and then rejoin the domain at the root "

will i be able to join the foundation server as member server to the windows server essential domain?

Comment: Could you link the page where you pulled the quote from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> joined at the root of the forest as a domain controller

Those are the requirements.

1. The member server must be joined as a domain controller,
2. and only at the root of your domain.

So no but yes, you won't be able to join Foundation as a *member server*, but you can promote it to a secondary domain controller of the root domain.